# bindParam as function argument doesn't pass value

Tags: php, pdo, bindparam

I have a question, namely - I have created a function that selects certain things from the base. I passed the function argument as bindParam, but I get an empty array. The only way in this case is to insert a variable from the argument directly into the query without binding. What is the reason for this?

```
function sampleFunction($test, $test2, $db) {

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SQL QUERY WITH :test AND :test2");
    $stmt->bindParam(':test', $test);
    $stmt->bindParam(':test2', $test2); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: What is the actual query? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: No, there is no reason. You should provide a code that supports your claim. [How to create MCVE for a PDO related problem](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: Query is correct, problem is with bindParam as argument of function

Comment: there is no such thing as "bindParam as argument of function". bindParam is bindParam, no matter whether it's called inside a function or not. Proceed to create a proof code and you'll see it yourself

Comment: @YourCommonSense but according to my reasoning, you are binary from a variable that is specified as a function parameter - so why does not it work?

Comment: probably your phone changed some words, I can't get what you mean

Comment: whatever your reasoning is, you should verify it. Proceed to create a proof code and verify it. It will take you less time than empty argument here in the comments